# Syncing private S3 data with CartoDB?

Tags: carto, amazon-s3

I've been using the new [Synced Table](http://blog.cartodb.com/post/65639747344/synced-tables-create-real-time-maps-from-data-anywhere) feature of CartoDB, and it's working great.

But some of the data I want to sync with is not public data. The data provider keeps it on S3, but requires authentication. Is there a way that I can use the sync tables if I have a password to access it? Can I plug that in to CartoDB somehow?

Comment: To many attempts so how do i u unlock with out username and email also pin i need it soon

Comment: I would like that functionality too.

Answer (score 1):

There's no option to import resources that require authentication to CartoDB directly. It will raise directly an error as CartoDB doesn't have access to the resource (because it doesn't have the logic to allow you to authenticate).